# Qt4 book says "make release", reality disagrees

Tags: qt4, debugging, qmake, gnu-make

According to various soures, for a Qt4 app you build the release or debug versions with "make release" or "make debug".   In real life, these give errors.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `debug'.  Stop
```

Only bare naked "make" works.  I'm not sure what it produces. Running "strip" does reduce the executables' size, but gdb isn't finding symbols in the unstripped file.  I'm using, qt4.6.2 on Arch Linux.

So what is the proper way to determine whether to make release or debug?

Comment: If you want help - post exact error messages, your compiler and operating system.

Comment: I think i worded this question badly.  Rewriting....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
CONFIG += debug_and_release
```

to your .pro file, then re-run qmake. You will then have the `debug` and `release` (capitalization!) targets available.

Comment: Okay, works, except the targets are all lower case for me.  "make release" is okay, but "make Release" doesn't find a target.  Nonetheless, this answer got me going, so thumbs up!

Comment: Must this line always be added manuallY?   Seems qmake -project won't put it in.

Comment: Oops, my bad, obviously you're right, had that remembered wrong... Editing the answer appropiately.

Comment: And yes, by default the .pro generator doesn't include this. Conceivably, you could edit the .prf files in mkspecs to change the defaults, but it's not that much of a hassle and I tend to avoid changing the vendor-supplied defaults files if I have a choice.